# Link error with global variable in header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I give an example very close to my code:

camera.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef VCL_CAMERA_TRACKING_H
#define VCL_CAMERA_TRACKING_H

extern int x;
....
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "camera.h"
...    
int x = 15;
```

b.cpp

```
#include "camera.h"
...
int example = 15;
int numFaces = 0;
...
if(numFaces<1) x = example;
...
```

when I build my project in VS10 I get "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int x" (?x@@3HA) at b.cpp".

It is strange because I have declared x in camera.h and defined it at main.cpp

Comment: See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/12574403#12574403

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585421/global-variable-declaration-with-extern

Answer (score 1):

You have *declared* your symbol:

```
extern int x;
```

But you haven't *defined* your symbol anywhere. You need to put

```
int x;
```

In one of your source files.

Comment: I think VS started to melt down. I defined x in b.cpp instead of main.cpp and it seems ok. thnx though!